# GIT shows multiple changes in project config, only line breaks are different (Mac)

Tags: projectconfig, git, phpstorm

Whenever I change something locally (Mac) in Craft (running in Nitro) which modifies my project-config, GIT (in PhpStorm) shows me many more changes in the change-list than necessary: Files are actually identical except for line breaks.

How can this be avoided?

Answer (score 3):

What helped me was changing the way GIT treats CRLF with this command:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

After running this command only real changes were tracked anymore.